# LNK 1104 - visual studio - exe file keeps being created

Tags: visual-studio-2015, system, linker-errors

I ran into a problem while working on a project that uses the ACE library, and MariaDB c++ conector for MySQL. I was doing some work as usual, changing thins and building constantly with no issues. I was changing some functions that make use of the MySQL connector and when I built the executable I got a series of linking errors to the MySQL connector (maybe this is relevant?). Thinking it was just a random glitch, I tried to build again and got the "lnk 1104 - can't open .exe file" error. Now when I check the folder where it is built (always working with the Debug version), the file seems to be constantly created. I can create files in the folder, I can modify files, but if I delete the .exe it is instantly created again.

Using MarkRussinovich's Process Explorer I can see that PID 4 is the one that keeps creating the file. I have already tried restarting my pc. Could this be something that is stuck trying to build, related to Visual Studio?

I'm clueless, thanks for any help!

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10 by the way. Also it happened again but now I'm not sure if the file is being created constantly or if the System just keeps handles for the file open forever. The first time the file was 0 kB and if I tried to open it on Notepad it said "the file doesn't exist, do you want to create it?". This time the file was stuck at 700 kB forever, but I didn't try to open it just went straight for the Safe Mode fix.

Comment: I managed to fix this temporarily by booting into safe mode, deleting the folder that contained the file and when I booted again the problem didn't happen again. However, I'm leaving the question open because it just happened again after building (I was able to fix it in the same way). It's as if System keeps handles on the file and won't let go no matter how much time passes or how many times you reboot.